# Implementing an in memory storage with B+ tree index

Tags: c++, memory, indexing

I'm trying to have an in memory data store that stores records in blocks. Note that a block may contain more than one record. Each block address is then indexed based on a record's field using a b+ tree index. Records are read from a TSV file.

What are some suggested ways of doing this in C++? I'm considering having a memory pool for storage, split into blocks, but I'm not sure how I would keep an index of each block's address.

Is this method recommended, or should I just stick to new() and delete() per record?

Currently, I'm creating a class for the B+ Tree, a class for the Storage, and a main.cpp, but I'm not sure what to include in each file.

Pretty new to C++, but have experience in other OOP languages (Java, Python, and some C). Any suggestions on implementation are much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: This is very vague. Why are you using addresses? `new` and `delete` are rarely used now in C++, since we have [smart pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=vs-2019). Give some examples.

Answer (score 0):

For an in-memory store, it does not matter much whether you use absolute addresses or indexes (relative to a base address) to identify your blocks. If you ever want to store your BTree to a file, however, the index approach will just work.

First, design your project around the following interface:

- `index_to_block`: takes an index, returns a block pointer.
- `new_block`: returns the index of a new block
- `free_block`: frees a block

During prototyping you can simply make block pointers the same as indexes. That means the interface is respectively the identity function, `new` and `delete`.

If you want to switch to a contiguous memory model later on, use `mmap` to get eg. a terabyte-sized chunk of memory. No worries, your OS will not back it with actual memory until you touch it. Now your `index_to_block` will do something like `reinterpret_cast<block*>(BASE_ADDRESS + idx * BLOCK_SIZE)` (if `BASE_ADDRESS` is a `uint8_t*`) or `&BASE_ADDRESS[idx]` (if `BASE_ADDRESS` is a `block*`). The other two functions will manipulate some kind of block freelist (or you can just always allocate new blocks).

Finally, I **highly** recommend reading the documentation on the [SQLite file format](https://sqlite.org/fileformat.html). It is a wonderful description of how a production-grade B-tree structure is implemented.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. The data is loaded from a tsv file and is not sequential. This necessitates that the indexing of the data be a dense index. Each block stores more than one (non sequential) record.

In that case, would it be better to index and load the data at the same time to get the address of each individual record within a block? At this point, I'm not sure how to "allocate" the blocks per se - do I simply create a block (e.g. a vector), fill it up with records, and store the block's address in the b+ tree index?

Comment: Definitely study how sqlite does it, then. IIRC, data is stored in a btree indexed by row ID, and additional indexes map the index column(a) to a row ID. Closely study the layout of data in a block and how blocks are organised in a btree and you will see that sqlite does not care whether rows are inserted in any specific order, or in batch or sequentially.

Comment: Not quite sure if I'm able to follow how SQLite does it - I'm quite new to this! The main concern I have is that all data is to be stored in the main memory. To achieve this, I'm trying to create a memory pool, split that pool into blocks of a fixed size, and then load each block with records from the data file. I will then maintain the block addresses, load them into a B+ tree index, and go from there. Does this make sense in theory?

Comment: Start simple: use block addresses as indices (so new/delete, as in my answer), and store *one row* per leaf block. Then work out the layout of a B-tree node block, and write code to add blocks to the tree (and the necessary block splitting operations). Then go back and rework the B-tree addition logic to enable multiple rows in one block. EDIT: I now see that there is no requirement that you use blocks for both leaf and node storage. Just create a B-tree data structure then that maps row IDs to blocks.